# How to extract every line from a stdOut in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, buffer, stdout, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm trying to get all the console outputs from a stream that in this case, the stream is from a Python console. This is a part of [a library](https://github.com/BobbyESP/spotdl-android) that I'm doing on GitHub; in it you can find all the code.

I have this function that calls a process:

```kotlin
 @JvmOverloads
    @Throws(SpotDLException::class, InterruptedException::class)
    fun execute(
        request: SpotDLRequest,
        processId: String?,
        callback: ((Float, Long, String) -> Unit)? = null
    ): SpotDLResponse {
        assertInit()
        //Check if the process ID already exists or not.
        if (id2Process.containsKey(processId)) throw SpotDLException("Process ID already exists")

        // disable caching unless it is explicitly requested
        if (!request.hasOption("--cache-path") || request.getOption("--cache-path") == null) {
            request.addOption("--no-cache")
        }
        //MANDATORY!
        request.addOption("--ffmpeg", ffmpegPath!!.absolutePath)

        val spotDLResponse: SpotDLResponse
        val process: Process
        var exitCode: Int = 0

        val outBuffer = StringBuffer() //stdout

        val errBuffer = StringBuffer() //stderr

        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val args = request.buildCommand()

        //Full command
        val command = mutableListOf<String>()
        command.addAll(listOf(pythonPath!!.absolutePath, spotdlPath!!.absolutePath))
        command.addAll(args)

        val processBuilder = ProcessBuilder(command)
        val env = processBuilder.environment()
        env["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = ENV_LD_LIBRARY_PATH!!
        env["SSL_CERT_FILE"] = ENV_SSL_CERT_FILE!!
        env["PATH"] = System.getenv("PATH")!! + ":" + binDir!!.absolutePath + ":" + ffmpegPath!!.absolutePath
        env["PYTHONHOME"] = ENV_PYTHONHOME!!
        env["HOME"] = HOME!!

        process = try {
            processBuilder.start()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw SpotDLException("Error starting process", e)
        }

        Log.d("SpotDL", "Started process: $process")

        if (processId != null) {
            id2Process[processId] = process
            Log.d("SpotDL", "Added process to map: ${processId[0].code}")
        }

        val outStream: InputStream = process.inputStream
        val errStream: InputStream = process.errorStream
        if(isDebug) Log.d("SpotDL", "Out stream: $outStream")
        if(isDebug) Log.d("SpotDL", "Err stream: $errStream")

        //1 - Default
        /*val stdOutProcessor = StreamProcessExtractor(
            outBuffer,
            outStream,
            callback
        )*/

        //2 - Test
        val stdOutProcessor = com.bobbyesp.library.tests.StreamProcessExtractor(
            errBuffer,
            errStream,
            callback
        )

        val stdErrProcessor = StreamGobbler(
            errBuffer,
            errStream
        )

        exitCode = try {
            stdOutProcessor.join()
            stdErrProcessor.join()
            process.waitFor()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            try {
                process.destroy()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.w("SpotDL", "Error destroying process or it was ignored", e)
            }
            if (processId != null) id2Process.remove(processId)
            throw e
        }

        if (processId != null) id2Process.remove(processId)

        val out = outBuffer.toString()
        val err = errBuffer.toString()

        //Delete ANSI (cleaner output)
        val outClean = out.replace("(?:\\x1B[@-Z\\\\-_]|[\\x80-\\x9A\\x9C-\\x9F]|(?:\\x1B\\[|\\x9B)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])".toRegex(), "")
        //Cleaner output
        val errClean = err.replace("(?:\\x1B[@-Z\\\\-_]|[\\x80-\\x9A\\x9C-\\x9F]|(?:\\x1B\\[|\\x9B)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])".toRegex(), "")

        if(exitCode > 0 && !command.contains("--print-errors")) {
            throw SpotDLException("Error executing command: $command, exit code: $exitCode, stderr: $err")
        }

        val elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime

        spotDLResponse = SpotDLResponse(command, exitCode, elapsedTime, outClean, errClean)

        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            //INFO/WARN: THE OUT IS EMPTY BECAUSE THE LAST LINE PROVIDED BY THE STREAMPROCESSEXTRACTOR IS EMPTY. Deleting it should make the out/err appear.
            //Update: It doesn't work that way but I think it's that it makes sense. Need to review and compare with youtubedl-android lib.
            Log.d("SpotDL", "Stdout: $outClean")
            Log.e("SpotDL", "Stderr: $errClean")
            Log.d(
                "SpotDL",
                "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            )
            Log.d("SpotDL", "Process: $processId finished with exit code: $exitCode")
            Log.d("SpotDL", "Process: $spotDLResponse")
        }

        return spotDLResponse
    }
```

and as you an see I have a StreamProcessExtractor, that is the Kotlin class that gets all the output of the console. The problem is that the stream is not able to get this line that is modified over the time and when it finishes, all the rest of the lines THAT ARE PRINTED appears; that line is the next:

```
Alan Walker - Shut Up                    Converting         ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╺━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━  66% 0:00:02
```

As I told, I have tried multiple StreamProcessExtractors but none worked. I leave here some of them. Hope that you can help me.

- Function used in all the extractors that is in the same class as run function:

```kotlin
    private fun processOutputLine(line: String) {
        //if is debug, print the line
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, line)
        //getProgress and getETA return a random value while I can't extract them from the non-shown line.
        callback?.let { it(getProgress(line), getEta(line), line) }
    }
```

StreamProcessExtractor (it has 3 constructors: `[private val buffer: StringBuffer, private val stream: InputStream, private val callback: ((Float, Long, String) -> Unit)? = null]`)

- 1

```kotlin
    override fun run() {
        try {
            //Read the stream and get the output line by line on real time
            val reader: Reader = InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(reader)
            var line: String?
            while (bufferedReader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                //Just read the line, cut that line in it's end and add it to the buffer. Then, the buffer will be read by the UI and after that, it will be cleared
                //clean output
                val matcher: Matcher = cleanOutRegex.matcher(line)
                val cleanLine = matcher.replaceAll("")
                if (cleanLine != "") {
                    processOutputLine(cleanLine)
                    //change the line length to 0, not the buffer
                    buffer.setLength(0)
                }
                continue
            }

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "failed to read stream", e)
        }
    }
```

- 2

```kotlin
    override fun run() {
        try {
            //Read the stream and get the output line by line on real time
            val reader: Reader = InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            var line: String?
            var nextChar: Int
            var arrayOfChars = ArrayList<String>()
            val currentLine = StringBuilder()
            while (reader.read().also { nextChar = it } != -1) {
                arrayOfChars.add(nextChar.toChar().toString())
                Log.d("StreamProcessExtractor", arrayOfChars.toString())
                if (callback != null) {
                    val line = currentLine.toString()
                    processOutputLine(line)
                    currentLine.setLength(0)
                    continue
                }
                currentLine.append(nextChar.toChar())

            }

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "failed to read stream", e)
        }
    }
```

- 3

```kotlin
override fun run() {
        try {
            //Option 1: Read the stream directly
            val reader: Reader = InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            val bytes = mutableListOf<Byte>()
            var c = reader.read()
            while (c != -1) {
                bytes.add(c.toByte())
                c = reader.read()
            }
            reader.close()

            //Option 2: Read the stream (but as Buffered)
            /*val buffer = BufferedInputStream(stream)
            val bytes = mutableListOf<Byte>()
            var c = buffer.read()
            while (c != -1) {
                bytes.add(c.toByte())
                c = buffer.read()
            }
            buffer.close()*/

            //file output stream to write file in the files directory

            val file = File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "output.bin"
            )
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            //Log the file location
            Log.d("StreamProcessExtractor", fileOutputStream.toString())
            fileOutputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray())
            fileOutputStream.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "failed to read stream", e)
        }
    }
```

- 4

```kotlin
    override fun run() {
        try {
            //Read the stream and get the output line by line on real time
            val reader: Reader = InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(reader)
            var line: String?
            while (bufferedReader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                //Just read the line, cut that line in it's end and add it to the buffer. Then, the buffer will be read by the UI and after that, it will be cleared
                //clena output
                val matcher: Matcher = cleanOutRegex.matcher(line)
                val cleanLine = matcher.replaceAll("")
                Log.d("StreamProcessExtractor", line.toString())
                callback?.let { it(1f, 1, line.toString()) }
                buffer.setLength(0)
                continue
            }

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "failed to read stream", e)
        }
    }
```

And some more deleted...
This has became a real headache for me... I'm trying to the the output of the SpotDL python library (you can find it on GitHub)

Thanks for the time!

Comment: Does `StreamProcessExtractor` use line-buffering? If so, you won't see the line-in-progress until the stream includes a newline character to move down to the next line. (Also, the line-in-progress is probably done using ANSI escape sequences to return the cursor to the start of the line; are you taking that into account when trying to view the result?)

Comment: I tried using char by char and line by line. None of them worked. And I don't really know how I should manage the ANSI espace sequences, so I need help on that haha. But the strange is that the byte reader also don't see that line...